# Git LFS not commiting large files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I am trying to add 2 files to git LFS. Here is the console output:[image]

But in Sourcetree I get this:

[image]

But in my repo it says:

[image]

I'm new to Git LFS so not sure the order of everything. I feel it's all setup ready to go but trying to commit I still get the error telling me to add them to LFS. Did i miss something?

Thanks